# is there any PyQt 5.10 for raspberry pi 3 for pip3 instal?

Tags: pip, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3

I installed PyQt5 to my raspberry pi 3 B+ via apt-get..

But it is looks like PyQt5.7 not 5.10. Which I need to use

```
out.setVersion(qt.QDataStream.Qt_5_10)
```

but this PyQt5 only has Qt_5_7.

Is there any PyQt5.10 or above there install able with pip3 or apt  ?

Comment: Try with pip though I suspect you can not because the binaries do not think they are compiled for ARM. so in this case the other option is to compile PyQt but this entails having installed Qt 5.10 in RPi which is also a headache. Why have you used QDataStream.Qt_5_10?

Comment: I want to exchange image between c++ and python . I used emqtd broker as middleware

Comment: And why do not you use QDataStream.Qt_5_7 ?, in Qt 5.10 you can use previous versions of QDataStream: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#setVersion

Comment: all other apps already in Qt_5_7  this is why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use PyQt5.11 properly you need to compile from the source for Raspberry pi .

First of all :

> SIP must be installed before building and using PyQt5. You can get the latest release of the SIP source code from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download.

The SIP installation instructions can be found at http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html.

Note When building PyQt5 v5.11 or later you must configure SIP to create a private copy of the sip module using a command line similar to the following:

**python configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip --no-tools**

Thank download PyQt5.11 and  :

**python3 configure.py**

after that:

**make
sudo make install**

You need to have installed Qt5.10 or later before this.
And be aware that which Qt is configure before above all commands.

Best